# Permiso denegado cuando intento instalar paquete "xlsx"

Tags: r

Al intentar instalar el siguiente paquete para exportar dataframe a CSV me da este mensaje:

```r
install.packages("xlsx")
```

La respuesta

```r
Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/file27cc7eef1e0d/xlsx/tests/log_plot.jpeg': Permission denied
```

Comment: Alguien me puede ayudar? como comento arriba: al intentar instalar un paquete muy básico para exportar dataframe a CSV me da este mensaje

Comment: Si instalas cualquier otro paquete ¿has tenido el mismo problema?

Comment: Fuera del problema, no es necesario `xlsx` para exportar a CSV. Utiliza `write.csv` (R base) o `write_csv` (readx)